# Mysql Stored Procedure OUT variable return NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using below sample stored procedure in my application:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`sp_item`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_item`(
    IN name VARCHAR(255),
    OUT item_id INT(11)
)
BEGIN   
    DECLARE item_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `item` (`name`) VALUES(name);   
    SET @item_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i execute this procedure using:-

```
CALL sp_item("TEST1",@item_id);
```

and fetch the last inserted id using:-

```
SELECT @item_id;
```

Then i get NULL as a result however the records is inserted successfully into database.

I could not find any relevant help after Googling.

What i am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using the out parameter (`item_id`). Instead, you're feeding a local variable with a similar name (`@item_id`). Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_item`(
    IN name VARCHAR(255),
    OUT item_id INT(11)
)
BEGIN   
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `item` (`name`) VALUES(name);   
    SET item_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    COMMIT;
END$$
```

Comment: So how then is it called?

Comment: @cerd You have to remove the leading `@`. I've edited the answer to make it more clear.